# how do I compute a weighted moving average using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas I can compute

- simple moving average SMA using `pandas.stats.moments.rolling_mean`
- exponential moving average EMA using `pandas.stats.moments.ewma`

But how do I compute a weighted moving average (WMA) as described in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing ... using pandas?

Is there a pandas function to compute a WMA?

Comment: 2 answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521507/compute-only-the-last-exponential-weighted-moving-average-pandas/75495234#75495234

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no implementation of that exact algorithm. Created a GitHub issue about it here:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/886

I'd be happy to take a pull request for this-- implementation should be straightforward Cython coding and can be integrated into `pandas.stats.moments`

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was about to add a feature request to github.  Then I saw the comment on http://pandas.pydata.org/community.html saying to ask here first.

Comment: The issue is closed in favour of getting something in statsmodels, but it's a bit hard to tell what's in statsmodels. There is an [ARMA model](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html#autogressive-moving-average-processes-arma-and-kalman-filter), and I guess you can use that, if you set the AR coefficient to 0?

Answer (score 17):

Using pandas you can calculate a weighted moving average (wma) using:
[.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) combined with [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) 

Here's an **example with 3 weights and window=3**:

```
data = {'colA': random.randint(1, 6, 10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

weights = np.array([0.5, 0.25, 0.25])
sum_weights = np.sum(weights)

df['weighted_ma'] = (df['colA']
    .rolling(window=3, center=True)
    .apply(lambda x: np.sum(weights*x) / sum_weights, raw=False)
)
```

**Please note** that in `.rolling()` I have used argument `center=True`.
You should check if this applies with your usecase or whether you need `center=False`.

Answer (score 1):

If `data` is a Pandas DataFrame or Series and you want to compute the WMA over the rows, you can do it using

```
wma = data[::-1].cumsum().sum() * 2 / data.shape[0] / (data.shape[0] + 1)
```

If you want a rolling WMA of window length `n`, use

```
data.rolling(n).apply(lambda x: x[::-1].cumsum().sum() * 2 / n / (n + 1))
```

as `n = x.shape[0]`. Note that this solution might be a bit slower than the one by Sander van den Oord, but you don't have to worry about the weights.

Comment: Can you explain why the sum of the cumulative sum of the reversed data is equal to `n * P_n + (n-1)* P_(n-1) + ... + P_1`. I tried it out on paper with n=3 and data=[1,2,3] but I can't figure out exactly whats going on, i.e. why 3 + 5 + 6 == 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1  (sum of cumsum == weighted sum)

Comment: No problem! Applying cumsum() to the reversed data `[3, 2, 1]` gives `[3, 3+2, 3+2+1] = [3, 5, 6]` and if you take the sum of these 3 elements you'll get `3 + 5 + 6 = 3 + (3+2) + (3+2+1) = 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1`. You see, the trick is how the cumsum() is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a kernel with the weights, and apply it to your series using `numpy.convolve`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def wma(arr, period):
    kernel = np.arange(period, 0, -1)
    kernel = np.concatenate([np.zeros(period - 1), kernel / kernel.sum()])
    return np.convolve(arr, kernel, 'same')

df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.arange(11)})
df['wma'] = wma(df['value'], 4)
```

Here I am interpreting WMA according to this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

For this type of WMA, the weights should be a linear range of n values, adding up to 1.0.

Note that I pad the front of the kernel with zeros. This is because we want a 'one-sided' window function, so that 'future' values in the time series do not affect the moving average.

`numpy.convolve` is fast, unlike `apply()`!
You can also use `numpy.correlate` if you reverse the kernel.